# Role based model for entities with different fields

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, roles

I am designing a web-application with multiple roles. Each user in given role is storing different information. Moreover it should be possible for user in role to change this role to another.

How do I design the database model? I have thought about two solutions so far.

**Solution 1:**

Create separate table for each role:

[image]

**Solution 2:**

Create common table:

[image]

Which would be better or how can I improve this database model?

Comment: Why you give the user the role row? The user's roles can all be fetched by the user_xxx tables.

Comment: @Ischuetze I think I dont understand your question.

Comment: For better understanding i made this [diagram](http://tinypic.com/r/2n8zwur/8). In this case it is possible to have row in system_user table with id 1 and role id 1 and in both tables - employee and company - can be row with id_user 1 which would be incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you accept my edit and edit your diagram into your question. Addind some paragraphs and structure to your question will help people reading it, too.